# How to display the number of pages in Pagination WebTable using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, javascript

I wan to display the number of pages in count in Pagination WebTable using **FOR Loop**, please find the code of **FOR Loop** condition. But not able to display the total number count of pages.

When clicking the next button till the last page displays, it should count of the number of clicks when clicking the next button and display the total count. The below is the Pagination image of WebTable. For example : As per Pagination image, 1 - 500 of 1822;501 - 1000 of 1822;1001 - 1500 of 1822;1501 - 1822 of 1822.Then the total number of page count is 4(required output)

```
Code where i am trying to use:
```

[image]

```
`Pagination Image`:
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What error(s) are you getting when you try to run your code? How far through your loop do you get?